# Show that matrix of T in base $\beta$ has $a + d =0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations

We have $T:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^2}$ given by $T \begin{bmatrix} x_1\\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2x_1\\ 3x_2 \end{bmatrix}$

We also know that $[T]_\beta = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$ for some base $\beta = \{v_1, v_2\}$ of $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Prove that $a+d=0$.

My proceedings go as follows:
From the given matrix one can find that $[T(v_1)]_\beta = \begin{bmatrix} a\\ c \end{bmatrix}$ and $[T(v_2)]_\beta = \begin{bmatrix} b \\ d \end{bmatrix}$.
Then if $v_1= \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $v_2= \begin{bmatrix} x_2 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix}$ we can find $T(v_1) = \begin{bmatrix} 2x_1 \\ 3y_1 \end{bmatrix}$ , $T(v_2) = \begin{bmatrix} 2x_2 \\ 3y_2 \end{bmatrix}$.

After this, I guess trying to change the base of one of the two pairs of vectors and solving a system of equations would give me the answer - but I tried this and got nowhere :(.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: This is a kind of "direct" approach. If anyone has a non-direct one (one that doesn't involve doing so many calculations) I'd like to see that.

Comment: Erm... Either that I got the question wrong, or you're trying to prove a false statement. Are you trying to prove the statement for *all* $\beta$? Because if so, the standard basis is a counterexample, and in fact any basis is

Comment: No. Not for all $\beta$. The statement is that for some fixed $/beta$ then we have that matrix.

Comment: Then the question is a bit misleading: as explained below me, there is no such basis that gives $a + d = 0$

Comment: So I re-read the question and in fact it is meant to be for every $\beta$. So yeah, it's a false statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For me your problem is wrong: if $\beta$ is the canonical base of $\mathbf{R}^2$, then a=2, d=3, b=c=0

But the thinq you can prove is: a+d=5
In fact, a+d represents the trace of T, which does not depend on the base you chose to write it's matrix.